# Jasmine expect(resultCode).toBe(200 or 409)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

For some test scenarios I run into the need of testing against multiple values which are all OK.

What I would like to do is something as follows:

```
expect(resultCode).toBeIn([200,409]);
```

This spec should pass when `resultCode` is either `200` or `409`. Is that possible?

**ADDED**
Thanks to peter and dolarzo for pointing me towards creating matchers. I had problems with addMatchers(). So, in the end I added the following to the jasmine.js:

```
jasmine.Matchers.prototype.toBeIn = function (expected) {
    for (var i = 0; i < expected.length; i++)
        if (this.actual === expected[i])
            return true;
    return false;
};
```

This gave me a working solution. I can now do the toBeIn as needed. (Jasmine 1.3.1)

Comment: Try checking out https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Matchers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to make something like this work:

```
 expect(3).toBeIn([6,5,3,2]);
```

Jasmine has a feature called matchers:

This is an example on how to declare them. I have declared at the very end the method you are looking for:

```
describe('Calculator', function(){
    var obj;
    beforeEach(function(){
        //initialize object
        obj = new Object();

        jasmine.addMatchers({
            toBeFive: function () {
                return {
                    compare: function (actual, expected) {
                        return {
                            pass: actual === 5,
                            message: actual + ' is not exactly 5'
                        }
                    }
                };
            },
            toBeBetween: function (lower,higher) {
                return {
                    compare: function (actual, lower,higher) {
                        return {
                            pass: ( actual>= lower   && actual <= higher),
                            message: actual + ' is not between ' + lower + ' and ' + higher
                        }
                    }
                };
            },
            toBeIn: function(expected) {
                    return {
                        compare: function (actual, expected) {
                            return {
                                pass: expected.some(function(item){ return item === actual; }),
                                message: actual + ' is not in ' + expected
                            }
                        }
                    };
                }
        });


    });
```

This is the matcher you need:

```
toBeIn: function(expected) {
                    return {
                        compare: function (actual, expected) {
                            return {
                                pass: expected.some(function(item){ return item === actual; }),
                                message: actual + ' is not in ' + expected
                            }
                        }
                    };
                }
```

**Important** with jasmine 2.0. I had to use **jasmine.addMatchers({** with jasmine specrunner.html but when I configured it with Karma I had to replace **jasmine** with **this** like **this.addMatchers({** because Karma use an earlier version of Jasmine.

Comment: Matchers it is ... thanks for the pointer. I tried your suggestion using the jasmine.addMatcher and the this.addMatcher ... both did not work. I'll have to figure out why, i think another question would be best because it involves requirejs/typescript.   Meanwhile i did put in a new matcher in the jasmine.js directly on the prototype and that works. I updated the question with the result I used.

Answer (score 0):

We can use expect().toContain() like this:

```
expect([200,409]).toContain(resultCode);
```

or not to contain:

```
expect([200,409]).not.toContain(resultCode);
```