# Jasmine - any boolean (jasmine.any(Boolean))

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I write unit tests for angular using karma, jasmine. Try to write:

```
expect(item).toEqual(jasmine.any(Boolean));
```

but got:

```
Expected true to equal <jasmine.any(function Boolean() { [native code] })>.
```

mm.. maybe i do something wrong) or is it another way to write test for value in that case:

if (true or false) - passed, if any other - fail

Comment: what is the expected value of item?

Comment: i have `item = true;`

Comment: @Dalorzo ok, so what a solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think what you need is a custom Matcher something like this:

```
toBeBoolean : function () {
  return {
    compare : function (actual, expected) {
      return {
        pass : (typeof actual === 'boolean'),
        message : 'Expected ' + actual + ' is not boolean'
      };
    }
  };
}
```

[How to create a Custom Matcher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20941702/1959948)

Comment: I glad it help you. It is also a nice way to extend Jasmine for more complex scenarios

Comment: I don't understand the use of `expected`.

Comment: the pass should be `(typeof actual === 'boolean')` instead of **expected**

Answer (score 9):

Also possible with:

```
expect(item).toMatch(/true|false/);
```

Answer (score 6):

I would expect your code work as expected but obviously it seems like jasmine behaves a little weird in this case.

I would recommend you the following workaround:

```js
expect(typeof item).toEqual('boolean');
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the marked solution isn't correct. At least not for the way I expect it to be used.
I did it like this:

```
jasmine.addMatchers({
    toBeBoolean: function () {
        return {
            compare: function (actual, expected) {
                return {
                    pass: typeof actual === 'boolean',
                    message: 'Expected ' + actual + ' is not boolean'
                };
            }
        };
    }
});
```

because you are not passing an expected value, just the actual.
So the way you would invoke this is:

```
expect(true|false).toBeBoolean();
```