# javascript expect.toBe with multiple values

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dst

I have problem related to daylight saving time. I have javascript jasmine test, where I test that opening time is correct. The opening times are stored in GMT-time, because they are gotten from backend api. The problem is, that the correct opening times cannot be tested with expect.toBe(certain_hour), because now when the daylight-saving went off, the opening hours won't be the same. Maybe it is stupid to try to store opening hours in GMT time anyway, since then the actual opening hour changes. But, how could I test the expect.toBe with multiple values? For now, I could test that expect.toBe(hour_one || hour_two), but that is not supported?

Answer (score 2):

Similar question as [Jasmine expect(resultCode).toBe(200 or 409)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20941343/7546092)

We can use expect().toContain() like this:

```
expect([200,409]).toContain(resultCode);
```

or not to contain:

```
expect([200,409]).not.toContain(resultCode);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const isOneOfThemTrue = statusCode === 200 || statusCode === 409;
expect(isOneOfThemTrue).toBe(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

The test code is still javascript, so when you write something like this:

```
expect.toBe(hour_one || hour_two)
```

It evaluates `hour_one || hour_two` as a logical expression. In javascript, when an expression of the form `a || b` is evaluated, the first non-falsy value of the two is returned, so `0 || 5` will return 5, but `2||5` will return 2.
Then this evaluation result, as a single argument, is passed to the `toBe()` function.

Comment: Doesn't work =/. It only takes the first argument, which it passes to toBe function.